# Unable to delete Ingress form EKS Modules using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, ingress-controller

I have deployed EKS Cluster and Load balancer through terraform, there is ingress being deployed in Cluster.

I have used AWS Provider with "5.17.0" Version.
I have also deployed an Namespace and Service along side the EKS Cluster using following module,
"terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws" with version "19.16.0"

When I tried to destroy the entire cluster, the terraform was not able to destroy alb-ingress, and through errors.

`module.eks.module.ingress.kubernetes_ingress_v1.test_ingress: Still destroying... [id=test/test-alb-ingress, 3m0s elapsed]`

╷
│ Error: Ingress (test/test-alb-ingress) still exists
│
│
╵

The above mentioned message keeps up for 20 minutes and then terraform returns error and doesn't delete the rest of resources.

I need to manually delete the alb-ingress so that terraform can progress to delete other resources.